# PostgreSQL: Revoke DELETE from public but nothing happen

Tags: postgresql

I grant select, update, insert and delete permission to public.

But when i tried to revoke the delete from public, but nothing happened.

I still able to delete row for the table.

Before:

```
ALTER TABLE ref_access_type
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE ref_access_type TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE ref_access_type TO public;
```

After execute:

```
REVOKE DELETE ON TABLE table_name FROM public;

ALTER TABLE ref_access_type
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE ref_access_type TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON TABLE ref_access_type TO public;
```

What I missing here?
thanks!

Comment: Wtat user do you use to connect to the server? Maybe postgres?

Comment: waaah.. forgot that I've use the user who create the database. thanks for reminding me. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you logged in as postgres?

Database superusers are not restricted by permission checks and that is the most likely explanation.

A second possibility is that you are the table owner and still  have permission.

To list permissions, use `\z ref_access_type` (that would help troubleshoot this problem).  Remember, permissions are additive in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.. Forgot that I've use the user who create the database.. silly me.. thanks though! ^_^